# How can I achieve the source code of hadoop in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

Here's the declaration for hadoop in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What I intend to do is to go into a method or class which belongs to hadoop (like `IntWritable`, etc). I've tried **right click on project -> Maven -> download sources**, But it seems no use.

Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look in central and see if there is a sources artifact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit [the search engine for Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.hadoop%7Chadoop-core%7C1.2.0%7Cjar), you will see that there are no 'sources' jar files pushed for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.0. If you then venture into org.apache.hadoop version 2.2.0, you will see various artifacts that do have sources. So, if you must use that version, you will have to manually download the source distribution.

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, the pom dependency only fetches the thing specified in their pom like jar or war export bundle. that does not come with sources, normally. Code navigation things only work with project specific class path declarations. (`.classpath` files) of each project individually.

An example entry looks like this in .classpath file of a project...

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```